# Let A and B be two sets. Then A − (A − B) ⊆ A ∩ B. Can anyone help me with the proof and text of this?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Edit: Here's how I tried:

[image]

I tried everything I could but to no avail.

Comment: What is it that you did try?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Assume $x\in A-(A-B)$...

Comment: If you show your work in the question, we may figure out where you went wrong.  [In fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292524/elementary-set-theory-proofs) $A-(A-B)=A\cap B$.

Comment: I developed (A - (A - B)) until I got an Empty set, but I am unsure if its correct or not

Comment: $\emptyset\cup (A\cap B)=A\cap B$, not $\emptyset$.  And [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  Assume $x\in A-(A-B)$.

Toward the end of what you tried, you essentially have $x\in A\cap \overline A$ or $x\in A\cap B$.

All you need to say then is  $x\not\in A\cap\overline A$, so $x\in A\cap B$.

It follows that $A-(A-B)\subseteq A\cap B$.