# Question regarding elementary set theory.

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading the accepted answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292524/elementary-set-theory-proofs?noredirect=1).

[image]

I am looking for an explanation of the following points:

1. How did we get $E$ \ $A_k$ $\subseteq \cup_{j=1}^nA_j$?
2. From this, how does it follow that $E\setminus\bigcap_{j=1}^nA_j\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^n(E\setminus A_j)$?

Comment: Were $x$ in all of the $A_k$ then $x$ would be in the intersection of the $A_k$, contrary to assumption.

Comment: $E\setminus A_k\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j$ can't be right; there's no connection given between $E$ and $(A_j)$.

Comment: Yes @DavidC.Ullrich that's why I am asking there is typo at linked question.

Comment: No, you're not asking that. Or at least you didn't ask that until you made that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you explain how we got $E \setminus A_k \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j$ ?

This is certainly a typo. What the text is intended to say is that $E \setminus A_k \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^n E \setminus A_j$, which is is trivially true since
$E \setminus A_k \subseteq (E \setminus A_k) \cup (\bigcup_{j=1}^n E \setminus A_j) = \bigcup_{j=1}^n E \setminus A_j$.

> how from this follows $E \setminus \bigcap^n_{j=1}A_j \subseteq \bigcup^n_{j=1}(E \setminus A_j)$?

The argument you cited starts with the assumption that $x \in E \setminus \bigcap^n_{j=1}A_j$ for a generic $x$, and it concludes that $x\in \bigcup^n_{j=1}(E \setminus A_j)$. Therefore, all the elements of $E \setminus \bigcap^n_{j=1}A_j$ are in $\bigcup^n_{j=1}(E \setminus A_j)$, that is, $E \setminus \bigcap^n_{j=1}A_j \subseteq \bigcup^n_{j=1}(E \setminus A_j)$.